# Como puedo ejecutar este codigo php 3 veces por ip cada 24 horas

Tags: php, wordpress

```
   function setPostViews($postID) {

        //check if user not administrator, if so execute code block within
        if( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {

        $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //retrieve the current IP address of the visitor
        $key = $user_ip . 'x' . $postID; //combine post ID & IP to form unique key
        $value = array($user_ip, $postID); // store post ID & IP as separate values (see note)
        $visited = get_transient($key); //get transient and store in variable

        //check to see if the Post ID/IP ($key) address is currently stored as a transient
        if ( false === ( $visited ) ) {

            //store the unique key, Post ID & IP address for 12 hours if it does not exist
            set_transient( $key, $value, 60*60*24 );

            // now run post views function
            $count_key = 'post_views_count';
            $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
            if($count==''){
                $count = 0;
                delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
                add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            }else{
                $count++;
                update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
            }


        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita algo más de información: ¿a qué te refieres con 3 veces por IP? ¿cómo controlas las IPs? ¿Qué servidor estás usando? Las preguntas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque no tienen un planteamiento adecuado y no son de ayuda para otros usuarios. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla).